# How to repeat header of paragraph using mail merge

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I am using MS Word to create template for PDF file.

Here is my file structure:

[image: file structure]

Now I expect all headings (i.e attendance key details, units, semaphores, sanction - big bold texts) are repeated across pages. But I have no idea how to do that. Does anyone know?

Comment: Could you show us what you already tried ?

Comment: @AnthonyRossi I have no idea to solve this problem , I have tried create a table with heading in first row and set "Repeat Header Rows" in MS Word , but it wrong !